# How do I download a pdf from a Javascript-generated POST request?

Tags: c#, ironpython

From what I can tell, the site requires a button click, which runs some Javascript and then sends a POST request. The POST request returns a pdf. All the solutions I've found for downloading a file either use WebClient (but I don't have a URL for the pdf) or HTTPRequest (which can't invoke a click).

I can get to the point of invoking the click with WebBrowser, and I can see using Fiddler that the pdf is getting returned in the site's response, but I have no idea how to get it onto my machine.

Comment: Doesn't Fiddler show you the ajax request?

Comment: That's a new term for me but if you mean the post request and headers and such, yes. However, some of the values in the post request seem to be dynamically generated by the site's Javascript or something. It uses a token of some sort that changes each time. Otherwise, I'd just use HTTPRequest.

Comment: That's probably a Cross Site Request Forgery Token. I don't know if you can access a response through the WebBrowser control. If not, you would have to provide very detailed request/response traces for anyone to be able to answer this question.

Comment: It does say CsrfToken, so that's definitely what it is. What about accessing a request through WebBrowser? If I could intercept the post request and cookies, maybe I could send them on though HTTPRequest instead? I'm at a bit of a loss here, honestly.

Comment: Without a code sample, it was hard to tell that this question dealt with C# and IronPython. While it looks like you got the help you needed this time, consider including a minimal example with your next question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using Selenium, with the following config settings passed into the Firefox driver:

```
profile = Firefox.FirefoxProfile()
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", saveDir)
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pdf")
profile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled",True)
profile.SetPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart", False)
profile.SetPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1", False)
profile.SetPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", False)
profile.SetPreference("browser.tabs.remote.force-enable", "false")
driver = Firefox.FirefoxDriver(profile)
```

Where `saveDir` is the target download directory. The first half of these config settings are to make Firefox download without a prompt, and the value for `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` is a MIME type. The second half of the configs prevent Firefox from crashing when `driver.Quit()` is called.